# Absolute position in inline block

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have some problem with position absolute with inline elements.

For example:

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="text">Proin porttitor sapien vitae felis maximus, in molestie sem egestas. Vivamus lacus orci, molestie eget nibh in, lobortis blandit risus.<span class="element"></span></span> Sed a diam sagittis, tempor ligula et, mollis velit. Ut quis est congue, vestibulum magna non, ullamcorper enim. Nam ultricies, est in elementum aliquet
```

Result: [image: example]

Need to get something like this:

[image]

The black line must be an HTML element.

Please, help me.

Comment: If it's a spoiler warning/censor bar sort of thing, couldn't you just wrap the text you want to cover with the span and let it do the positioning for you?

Comment: @DBS Yes, it is censor, but I want to make it a little interactive. Please, see my REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/9fc6a5587a8346aeaecbf520e0ca6b64?version=3.20.1 (drag black rectangle)

Comment: This may seem simple but it's really complex, we need an inline element as the cover  to follow the flow on the text which is inline, But we can't specify width/height on inline elements so we can't see be 100% of your parent, Also we need to overlap, the only options for overlapping are floats position absolute and css grid, absolute and css grid changes the layout to block level which is not what we want, and floats previous issue can't specify width/height, Even with a script it will be tricky because we need to construct a weird shape respecting a lot of variables.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way i can think of is to double up the markup and align them on top of each other then cover the portion you want.

```css
[container] {
  position: relative;
  animation: alter 5s linear infinite alternate;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

[text],
[mask] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

[mask] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #d9020200;
}

[mask]>[cover] {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes alter {
  to {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<div container>
  <span text>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus veritatis, corporis eos aperiam ex eum corrupti modi error incidunt. Ipsam enim similique dolore unde ratione facere libero hic minus accusamus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus veritatis, corporis eos aperiam ex eum corrupti modi error incidunt. Ipsam enim similique dolore unde ratione facere libero hic minus accusamus.
    </span>
  <span mask>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus veritatis, corporis eos aperiam ex eum <span cover>corrupti modi error incidunt. Ipsam enim similique dolore unde ratione facere libero hic minus accusamus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </span>Necessitatibus
  veritatis, corporis eos aperiam ex eum corrupti modi error incidunt. Ipsam enim similique dolore unde ratione facere libero hic minus accusamus.
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your text, then we can color text:

```css
.spoiler {      
  color:transparent;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <span class="spoiler"> 1 start Proin porttitor sapien vitae felis maximus, in molestie sem egestas.
            Vivamus lacus orci, molestie eget nibh in, lobortis blandit risus. 1 start
        </span>
        Sed a diam sagittis, tempor ligula et, mollis velit. Ut quis est congue, vestibulum magna non, ullamcorper enim. Nam ultricies, est in elementum aliquet
    </p>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want color text. I want to get html element for add  ainteractive. Please, see REPL for example https://svelte.dev/repl/9fc6a5587a8346aeaecbf520e0ca6b64?version=3.20.1 (drag black rectangle)